Patching CUs for SQL server in MIrroring & Transactional replication Topology
we have SQL server HA+DR solution in production built using DB mirroring combined with Transactional Replication with distributor and subscriber on the same remote DR SQL server instance. on researching how to patch this topology with Cumulative updates, the only documentation from Microsoft assumes if Distibutor exists on a separate SQL server than subscriber, referencing the same document if I had to perform rolling updates on the SQL instances, does the below order make sense? any guidance is appreciated.

The mirror.
The witness.
The distributor/The subscriber(s).
The principal/publisher.

P.S. the setup only exists in production, no way to test it out
reference:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/sql/database-engine/replication/install-service-packs-hotfixes
